# Store an ID before installing an app from QR code

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo, app-store, mobile-development

I'm aware that I can create a QR code a user can scan to go to my mobile app's page on App Store or Google Play and install it.

My question is if there's a way for me to include a specific ID in the QR code that I can store on the device **"prior"** to installation when the user scans the QR code. Then after the installation I want my app to check for this ID.

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve. The client we're building the app for has an affiliate program and wants to know which affiliate got a user to install their app. So, the QR code would be specific to the affiliate. All QR codes will point to the same app on App Store and Google Play but also include the affiliate's ID.

This is fairly easy to achieve on a web app. Just not sure if it's possible on mobile apps.

BTW, we're building the app in React Native/Expo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to to use Firebase Dynamic Links as the data survives the install process.
More info here: https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwY-LBhD6ARIsACvT72OZlyBErL-gjPmnRvp6j52z061PhD6KMEQ4EmLARIdWCqDL1jje-W0aAhNyEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Thank you. You also opened the door for me to learn about things like Branch - https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/

Comment: Great to hear you comment you’re the politest guy i’ve met on this site

Comment: Unfortunately SO discourages thanking for answers. I think their idea is that SO should be used like a knowledge base. That’s why they also hate duplicate questions. I’m not a fan of SO rules/etiquette either and if I find a similar community, I’ll move on but currently this is where you’ll find better quality answers to coding questions.